# Drawable Resource in Mapbox Android

Tags: android, resources, mapbox, symbols, drawable

I have some icons as drawable resources that I would like to put in specific locations in a MapBox map in android studio, but I don´t know how.

I have tried converting my resource files into bitmaps, and then convert those bitmaps into strings so as to fill the "withIconImage" method of SymbolOptions class.(I know it works with defined strings such as "airport", "fire-station").

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/api-response-icon-update/) from the Mapbox Android documentation shows how to add a local drawable resource from an Android application to your Mapbox map as a `SymbolLayer`. The `initSpaceStationSymbolLayer` helper method specifically takes care of this:

```
private void initSpaceStationSymbolLayer(@NonNull Style style) {
  style.addImage(
    "space-station-icon-id",
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.iss)
  );

  style.addSource(new GeoJsonSource("source-id"));

  style.addLayer(new SymbolLayer("layer-id", "source-id").withProperties(
    iconImage("space-station-icon-id"),
    iconIgnorePlacement(true),
    iconAllowOverlap(true),
    iconSize(.7f)
  ));
}
```

You mentioned `SymbolOptions`, however, so it is likely the case that you are using the [Mapbox Annotation Plugin for Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/) rather than directly adding `SymbolLayer`s. As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/plugins/annotation/0.8.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/annotation/SymbolOptions.html) for the `SymbolOptions#withIconImage` method, icon images are specified as `String`s which reference the names of images in your style's [sprite](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/sprite/) sheet. [This example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java) from the Mapbox Android Plugins demo app demonstrates how to add an image from the resources folder to your style, to then be used as the icon image in a `SymbolManager`. Namely, `ID_ICON_AIRPORT` is defined as `"airport"` [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/34dda7b88bb8cea4f8bacc8379234fa443dd0c4f/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java#L51), then the helper method `addAirplaneImageToStyle` [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/34dda7b88bb8cea4f8bacc8379234fa443dd0c4f/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java#L162-L166) adds the relevant image to the style, and finally a `Symbol` is created [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/34dda7b88bb8cea4f8bacc8379234fa443dd0c4f/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java#L99-L106) using `SymbolOptions#withIconImage` and `ID_ICON_AIRPORT` passed as the argument. You use this same approach for adding your own drawable image.